# PHP thread don't work

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

I use php_thread to do a multithreading.
http://php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php

Installation was successful but I got a bad result

My code is here :

```
<?php

class workerThread extends Thread {
public function __construct($i){
  $this->i=$i;
}

public function run(){
    for ($i=0; $i < 3; $i++) { 
        echo "Thread-".$this->i."=>".$i."<br/>";
    }
}
}

for($i=0;$i<2;$i++){
$workers[$i]=new workerThread($i);
$workers[$i]->start();
}


?>
```

Result:

```
Thread-0=>0
Thread-0=>1
Thread-0=>2
Thread-1=>0
Thread-1=>1
Thread-1=>2
```

The function does not realize the "Multithreading". Could I get some help ?

Comment: So even though you told it to start 5 threads, it only ran 2? Is that the problem you're having?

Comment: No, It works in a sequential not asynchronous way. The 1st thread  ends before 2nd begin

Comment: That may be just because the threads run so quickly, there isn't enough time for another thread to start. Just because they _can_ be interleaved doesn't mean they _will_ be. Try putting `sleep(rand(1, 5))` into the loop in `run` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid having echo in the run function.
It can generates bugs and stuck the workers in infinite loops.

Let the threads come back with join().
Only there, retrieve your datas and have an echo.

Comment: I did it (without echo), but it is a same problem. Also I used join().